# I want a docked bottom navigation bar in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want a docked bottom navigation bar in flutter where the item in the center is uplifted and fixed[image: this is the type of navigation bar i want],
any idea how can I do that

this is the output that I want and I don't have any idea I can I do that
[image: this is the type of bottom navigation bar i want]

Comment: you want above image like `bottom-navigation-bar`?

Comment: yes I want above image like bottom navigation bar @RavindraS.Patil

Comment: @ Om Shivam refer my below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding floating action button in scaffold

```
  Scaffold(
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
    child: Row(
      children: [
        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.menu), onPressed: () {}),
        Spacer(),
        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.search), onPressed: () {}),
        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert), onPressed: () {}),
      ],
    ),
  ),
  floatingActionButton:
      FloatingActionButton(child: Icon(Icons.add), onPressed: () {}),
  floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
),
```

Answer (score 1):

See I have two options for you here (potentially three):

**1. Create a mix of `bottom-navigation-bar` and `floating-action-button`**

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          shape:
              RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
          child: Icon(Icons.video_call),
        ),
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
          color: Colors.redAccent,
          notchMargin: 5,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.menu,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.search,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.print,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.people,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

**pseudo second:**

Create a notch in the `bottom-navigation-bar` :

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
          shape: shape: AutomaticNotchedShape(
        RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
            top: Radius.circular(15),
          ),
        ),
        RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
        ),
      ), // by adding this line in the above code
          color: Colors.redAccent,
          notchMargin: 5,
          child: Row(
```

**2. Use Stack BottomNavBar Combo :**

```
Stack(
            children: [
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: BottomNavigationBar(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    items: const [
                      BottomNavigationBarItem(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.home,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          label: 'a',
                          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent),
                      BottomNavigationBarItem(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                          label: 'a',
                          backgroundColor: Colors.yellow),
                      BottomNavigationBarItem(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                        label: 'a',
                        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                      ),
                      BottomNavigationBarItem(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                        label: 'a',
                        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                      ),
                    ],
                    type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
                    selectedItemColor: Colors.black,
                    iconSize: 20,
                    elevation: 5),
              ),
                      Positioned(
                        top: height * 0.25,
                        left: width * 0.40,
                        child: FloatingActionButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                          child: Icon(Icons.video_call),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
Scaffold(
  body: Container(),
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
    onPressed: () {},
    tooltip: 'Increment',
    child: Icon(Icons.video_camera_back),
    elevation: 4.0,
    backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
  ),
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.home), onPressed: () {}),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.show_chart), onPressed: () {}),
        ),
        Expanded(child: new Text('')),
        Expanded(
          child: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.tab), onPressed: () {}),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.settings), onPressed: () {}),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
  floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
)
```

Result-> [image]

Refer [`persistent_bottom_nav_bar`](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar) also and refer [bottom_nav_bar](https://fluttergems.dev/bottom-navigation-bar/) also for more design of